# SSDT does not consider trigger enable/disable property

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I have created an SSDT project from an existing database. It included existing trigger inside the tablename.sql file.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableName] (
    [ID]        INT           NULL
)

GO

CREATE TRIGGER trgTableName ON dbo.TableName
FOR INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
 ....
END

GO

DISABLE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgTableName] ON [dbo].[TableName]; /* My trigger is currently disabled */
GO
```

However, whenever I modify my trigger, SSDT enables it again. It does not consider Trigger disable property while deployment.

Is there anyway I can get SSDT to disable the trigger (if it is disabled already on the database)?

One of the ways I am thinking is to add as a post deployment script. However, it would be good to use existing SSDT feature for this instead of manually adding a post deployment script.

EDIT: It looks like SQL server automatically enables a trigger if we update them. In my case, there is an update to the trigger so it enables the trigger. However, SSDT does not disable it after the update.

Comment: Just mentioning, after importing a database, we move trigger definitions to their own files. This makes them slightly easier to manage. Don't have any disabled ones, so can't help with this question.

Comment: No problem, I think I will do the same - it is much cleaner approach.

Comment: I've lost count of the number of subtle [issues within SSDT](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server?query=ssdt) that resulted in an unexpected outcome.  I love the idea of desired state deployments but in the end edge cases like this lead to us dropping SSDT.

Comment: Could you check the state of deployment property: Ignore DML trigger state?

Comment: [@DavidRushton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2572928/david-rushton) You might be using the wrong forums for raising issue with SSDT. You should try raising those issues using Visual Studio into their [developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search.html?type=question+OR+problem+OR+idea&q=SSDT) to get faster response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is of course to move it to PostDeploy. But I suggest to create a single stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mysp_disable_triggers
AS
BEGIN
    DISABLE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgTableName] ON [dbo].[TableName];
END;
```

and call it inside post deploy script:

```
EXEC mysp_disable_triggers;
```

This way you have a single point of reference and your code is still validated(checking if references exist and it is a proper SQL code).

---

Second approach to be checked is using `ALTER TABLE` syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableName](...);
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgTableName] ...;
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trgTableName] DISABLE TRIGGER [dbo].[TableName];
```

EDIT: It does not change the behaviour. So the PostDeploy apporach seems to be feasible option.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, does it mean it is a bug in SSDT / Visual Studio that it is not able to detect that the trigger is disabled and it should disable the trigger even if it has been modified? My SQL scripts were generated from an existing database using SSDT create project feature.

Comment: @developer My understaning is that every time table/trigger changes, the trigger has to be altered(and enabled). The disable seems not to take effect so PostDeploy is an option.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a big hard-to-manage database and there's lots of this kind of stuff, you might get tricky and create a procedure that scripts out a procedure that captures the state of your triggers and restores them. You can run the procedure at PreDeploy and then run the generated procedure at PostDeploy. Something like this:

```
create procedure dbo.scriptResetDisableTriggers as 
begin
    set nocount on
    declare 
        @sql nvarchar( max ),
        @n nvarchar( 2 ) = nchar(0x0d) + nchar(0x0a)

    select @sql =  
        N'create procedure dbo.resetDisabledTriggers as' + @n +
        N'begin' + @n +
        N'  set nocount on' + @n + @n;

    select @sql += 
        N'  begin try' + @n +
        N'    disable trigger ' +  tr.name + N' on table ' + s.name + N'.' +    t.name + @n +
        N'  end try' + @n +
        N'  begin catch' + @n +
        N'    print( error_message( ) ) -- or something else cool' + @n +
        N'  end catch' + @n + @n
    from 
        sys.triggers tr
        inner join
        sys.tables t
        on
            tr.parent_id = t.object_id
        inner join
        sys.schemas s
        on
            t.schema_id = s.schema_id
    where
        tr.is_disabled = 1

    select @sql +=  
        @n + N'  drop procedure dbo.resetDisabledTriggers' + @n +
        @n + N'end' + @n

    print ( @sql )
    execute sp_executesql  @sql

end
```

Comment: BTW: Not sure if it's a bug in SSDT per se. It may be that it's defined SQL Server behavior. Haven't studied this particular phenomenon.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems to be a SQL server behavior that it enables the trigger. However, SSDT should have disabled it to preserve the same state - which seems to be a bug.

Comment: Yeah - I could see that. There's a LOT of transformation that SSDT does from an SSDT project to sync to a db...but protecting the state of triggers doesn't look like anything SSDT is interested in. I could see that as a bug, I suppose.

Comment: I would like to think of this more as a suggestion. If you agree you can post this in Visual Studio developer community as a [Suggestion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=8)